# Make 2nd form return input focus to 1st form in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, forms

I’ve searched the web for an answer to this but can’t find it.  It seems a common enough issue that I’m puzzled to not find anything.

I have 3 forms
Form A  the form a user would be working on;
Form B  a menu for selecting a form C to display;
Form C  a ‘Quick List’ of data in the database to aid in entering into Form A.  There are several of these Form C's that could be displayed during a session.

- The user while working on Form A can press control-Q which will display the menu Form B.
- Control automatically passes to Form B where the user presses a single key and the desired Form C pops up and Form B closes.
- Control is passed to Form C and it is the ‘active’ form.

There is nothing to fill in on Form C so I want to automatically return to the last active control on Form A.

Everything works just fine but I end up with Form C as the active form.

How can I force control back to the last active control on Form A?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post this question and answer. Would you consider posting source code? I found this a little hard to follow and the code listing may make things clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it.  And there were several issues to solve.  Not sure if this is the best way but it does work.

The first problem is to be able to refer to the form you want to have focus from some other form.  I overloaded the ‘show’ event for both Form B and Form C to be able to pass the original calling form.  When I called Form B from Form A, I supplied a reference to Form A.  Then when I called Form C I passed the reference to Form A again.  At that point both Form B and Form C knew who the originator was.

I tried to set the focus back to Form A within Form C.  So in both Form B and Form C, I would set a variable (Dim ‘callingform’ as Form).  In each of Form B and C I used the following:

Dim callingform as Form

Overloads Sub Show(ByVal f1 As Form)

Callingform = f1

So each of Form B and Form C had a reference to the original Form A that was to eventually get the focus.

But you can’t refer to the form with that variable.  The following is a proper reference to the form and ‘focus’ is the method to change focus.

CType(callingform, windows.forms.form).focus()

That statement seems straightforward enough but I was trying to use it in the wrong place.  I was using that statement at the end of the ‘Load’ event for Form C.  The problem there is that Form C hasn’t yet gotten focus so executing that statement would be subsequently overridden as Form C was actually displayed.  I didn’t know then but do now, Focus isn’t transferred to the new form until AFTER the load event.  So if you put that statement in the Form C ‘GotFocus’ event it works like a charm.

After considering things for awhile, I’ve decided that Form C might be called from anywhere and it shouldn’t be deciding where focus should be set.  It should be decided by whoever decided to Display Form C.

So I have put the following in the end of Form B’s Menu selection code:

FormC.Show(formA)       ‘Display Form C and pass the originating form)

CType(formA, windows.forms.form).focus()     ‘Change focus to FormA, the originating form

formB.Close    (actually -  me.close)  - ‘ Close up the menu form, FormB

(Aside:  I don’t really understand why the ‘ctype’ is necessary.  I passed the form as a ‘form’ and defined the variable ‘callingform’ as a form.  I expected to be able to just say callingform.focus().  )

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant code for my answer.

Partial Code:
In Form A (The original calling form)

```
If CurMode = Browse Then

  'Check for Quick List menu CRTL-Q
  If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Q Then

   ' Call the 'Menu form, FormB
    CType(Me.MdiParent, frmRECORDmain).ShowQuickListMenu(Me, Me.ActiveControl)
    Exit Sub
  End If
```

In QuickList Menu form  (The original Form B)

```
Public Class frmQuickListMENU
Dim CallingForm As Form
Dim CallingControl As Control
Dim Selection As String

' This is so that Form B will know who Form A was.
Overloads Sub Show(ByVal f As Form,
                 ByVal c As Control,
                 Optional PreSelection As String = "")
CallingForm = f
CallingControl = c
Selection = PreSelection
Show()
End Sub

Private Sub frmQuickListMENU_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
Select Case e.KeyCode
  Case Keys.D1, Keys.NumPad1
  . .       
  Case Keys.D3, Keys.NumPad3
  . . .
  Case Keys.D6, Keys.NumPad6
  . . .
  ' One of 12 Menu choices which will open 1 of 12 Form C's
  Case Keys.D7, Keys.NumPad7
    Dim frmquickListPHD1 As New frmQuickListPHD()
    frmquickListPHD1.MdiParent = MasterParentForm
    frmquickListPHD1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    frmquickListPHD1.Location = New Point(QLPHD.Left, QLPHD.Top)
    ' Show Form C  
    frmquickListPHD1.Show(CallingForm, CallingControl, Me)
End Select
'    ************************
'    ************************
'    THE NEXT LINE IS THE 'MAGIC' I WAS LOOKING FOR
'    This line returnbs focus back to the original Form A
'    ************************
CType(CallingForm, Windows.Forms.Form).Focus()
Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub frmQuickListMENU_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Dim x1 As Integer
  x1 = Me.Width
End Sub
End Class
```

And Finally the code for the 'Quick List' - Form C
However, since I have decided to change the focus in the Form B code instead of the Form C code none of the Form C code is relevant.  I only show it to be consistent with my original post.

```
  Dim callingform As Form
  Dim callingcontrol As Control
  Dim MenuForm As Form


' The following was initially required so that the change of focus could be made within this 
' Class but I have since changed my mind and the Overload is unnecessary.  I only left 
' this here  so the code would be consistent with my original note.  I'll  be removing
' thisOverload of the 'Show' event. 
Overloads Sub Show(ByVal f1 As Form,
                   ByVal c As Control,
                   ByVal f2 As Form)
  callingform = f1
  MenuForm = f2
  callingcontrol = c
  Show()
End Sub

Private Sub frmQuickListPHD_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Try
  conn.Open()
  DA.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(SQL, conn)
  ' 
'
'
Catch ex As Exception
  Console.WriteLine("Error" & ex.ToString)
Finally
  conn.Close()
End Try
Me.Height = QLPHD.Height
Me.Width = QLPHD.Width
'
'
'  More form layout code
'
' 
'
 End Sub
End Class
```